# Validação de formulário em HTML5

Tags: css, html5, front-end

Estou fazendo um formulário de validação usando o HTML5 e suas próprias tags para validar os campos. Estou usando a **PATTERN**, que limita o tipo de caractere. Mas não funciona... Os campos não estão sendo bloqueados. "Codigo", apenas numeros e "Nome", apenas letras.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<form>
Codigo: <input type="text" required="required" name="number" pattern="[0-9]"></input>

Nome: <input type="text" required="required" name="text" pattern="[a-z]"></input> 
</form>
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Acredito que vai te ajudar: http://wbruno.com.br/html/validando-formularios-apenas-com-html5/

Comment: Na verdade ela funciona, o atributo `pattern` não evita que o usuário digite valores que não estão na expressão regular e sim evita que esses valores sejam enviados pelo formulário. Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Adicionalmente, caso você queira impedir o usuário de digitar valores não aceitados você pode fazer isso facilmente utilizando o plugin `jQuery Mask` (http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

Comment: Na verdade, assim que eu terminei este post comecei a perceber isso... Que são apenas para expressões regulares e não há bloqueio dos campos, que é o que quero. Rodrigo, obrigado pelos links, irão ajudar muito! Obrigado a todos por confirmarem o que estava achando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A validação não bloqueia os campos, apenas marca seu estado como inválido. Se você alterar o estilo do campo inválido, isso ficará visível:

```css
input:invalid {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
Codigo: <input type="text" required="required" name="number" pattern="[0-9]">
Nome: <input type="text" required="required" name="text" pattern="[a-z]">
</form>
```

Repare que as regras que você colocou são para **1** número no primeiro campo, e **1** letra (minúscula) no segundo. Se quiser validar múltiplos números e letras precisaria alterar as expressões regulares para `[0-9]+` e `[a-z]+`.

Comment: Vale citar que o atributo pattern trabalha com expressões regulares.

Comment: Fiz uma edição breve para incluir o termo